# Data Table in XML String to SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I was hoping someone could provide a small example of sending a data table in an XML String into an SQL table.  I've been searching this site and the internet but the examples I've found have different XML layouts. I'm not experienced enough to apply those examples to mine.  Here is what the XML looks like, the data I want is at the end, in the "rs:data" section, note: this could be a couple 1000 lines:

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = '<xml xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
    <x:PivotCache>
        <x:CacheIndex>1</x:CacheIndex>
        <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
            <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">
                <s:attribute type="Col1"/>
                <s:attribute type="Col2"/>
                <s:attribute type="Col3"/>
                <s:attribute type="Col4"/>
                <s:attribute type="Col5"/>
                <s:attribute type="Col6"/>
                <s:attribute type="Col7"/>
                <s:attribute type="Col8"/>
                <s:attribute type="Col9"/>
                <s:extends type="rs:rowbase"/>
            </s:ElementType>
            <s:AttributeType name="Col1" rs:name=" Date">
                <s:datatype dt:type="dateTime"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="Col2" rs:name=" PlantId">
                <s:datatype dt:maxLength="255"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="Col3" rs:name=" Provider">
                <s:datatype dt:maxLength="255"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="Col4" rs:name=" Pipeline">
                <s:datatype dt:maxLength="255"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="Col5" rs:name=" Group">
                <s:datatype dt:maxLength="255"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="Col6" rs:name=" Type">
                <s:datatype dt:maxLength="255"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="Col7" rs:name=" Description">
                <s:datatype dt:maxLength="255"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="Col8" rs:name=" DataType">
                <s:datatype dt:maxLength="255"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
            <s:AttributeType name="Col9" rs:name=" DataValue">
                <s:datatype dt:type="float"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
        </s:Schema>
        <rs:data>
            <z:row Col1="2015-01-01T00:00:00" Col2="CH1" Col3="ENOGEX" Col4="ENOGEX" Col5="Fixed" Col6="Transport" Col7="Monthly Reservation" Col8="Cost" Col9="9483.1183870967743"/>
            <z:row Col1="2015-01-02T00:00:00" Col2="CH1" Col3="ENOGEX" Col4="ENOGEX" Col5="Fixed" Col6="Transport" Col7="Monthly Reservation" Col8="Cost" Col9="9483.1183870967743"/>
            <z:row Col1="2015-01-03T00:00:00" Col2="CH1" Col3="ENOGEX" Col4="ENOGEX" Col5="Fixed" Col6="Transport" Col7="Monthly Reservation" Col8="Cost" Col9="9483.1183870967743"/>
            <z:row Col1="2015-01-04T00:00:00" Col2="CH1" Col3="ENOGEX" Col4="ENOGEX" Col5="Fixed" Col6="Transport" Col7="Monthly Reservation" Col8="Cost" Col9="9483.1183870967743"/>
            <z:row Col1="2015-01-05T00:00:00" Col2="CH1" Col3="ENOGEX" Col4="ENOGEX" Col5="Fixed" Col6="Transport" Col7="Monthly Reservation" Col8="Cost" Col9="9483.1183870967743"/>
            <z:row Col1="2015-01-06T00:00:00" Col2="CH1" Col3="ENOGEX" Col4="ENOGEX" Col5="Fixed" Col6="Transport" Col7="Monthly Reservation" Col8="Cost" Col9="9483.1183870967743"/>
        </rs:data>
    </x:PivotCache>
</xml>'
```

All the data i want is within the "rs:data" section.  It's 9 columns by however many rows.  Each row in the XML is started with "z:row".  Here is what i've tried, this query executes without errors, showing my column headers, but no data:

```
DECLARE @TempTbl TABLE ([Date] datetime, PlantId varchar(50), Provider varchar(50), Pipeline varchar(50), [Group] varchar(50), 
    [Type] varchar(50), [Description] varchar(50), DataType varchar(50), DataValue float) 

INSERT INTO @TempTbl 
SELECT  Tbl.Col.value('@Col1', 'datetime'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col2', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col3', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col4', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col5', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col6', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col7', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col8', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col9', 'float')
FROM @xml.nodes('//row') Tbl(Col) 

--See the table 
SELECT * FROM @TempTbl
```

Comment: I show what i've tried with the sql statement at the bottom of my original post with the insert into my temp table. I was hoping for an example of how to query my xml string and put the xml data table into an sql table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **respect** and include the **XML namespaces** in your document!

Try this:

```
-- define the relevant XML namespaces you need
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' AS x, 
                   'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' AS rs,
                   '#RowsetSchema' AS z)
INSERT INTO @TempTbl 
    SELECT  
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col1', 'datetime'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col2', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col3', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col4', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col5', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col6', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col7', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col8', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        Tbl.Col.value('@Col9', 'float')
    FROM @xml.nodes('/xml/x:PivotCache/rs:data/z:row') Tbl(Col) 

--See the table 
SELECT * FROM @TempTbl
```

This should give you the attribute values into the table variable

Comment: Yes!! Exactly what I was looking for thank you very much for your time, help and patience.  I see that I got some "negative" marks on research, but research is exactly what i'm trying to do.  Look, I'm not a developer, I do financial modeling.  I have a meeting with our professional developers on tuesday where I'm going to ask them for a stored procedure.  I wanted to know what I was asking them for.  I build an excel model that outputs data we need to get into DWH, I found that I can pass an xml string to a sp that could then do the upsert stuff.  Creating the XML is easy for me:

Comment: easy for me in VBA.  But I wanted to see what hurdles I was asking of our IS staff.  Other options might be to export .csv's that then could have sheduled ETL's run on, but then you have lag.  These developers also made a com wrapper excel addin to read from our ODS/DWH, but using that creates dependancy in excel book, and they still have to write a write function into it, so I thought about a sp solution with passing xml.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @erock: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.